# POSIX threads vs parallelism

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

Do POSIX threads (managing by pthread library) works parallelly? My lecturer has told us that this library creates only user threads, that are not managed by Linux kernel. I wrote some code that fill large matrix and compared times of execution for threads and whole program and it seems to works parallelly. Can I use this library to creating parallel programs with threads which are recognized by kernel?

Comment: Maybe your lecturer is thinking of Windows?  From `man 7 pthreads`: *Threads do not share process IDs.  (In effect, LinuxThreads
          threads are implemented as processes which share more information
          than usual, but which do not share a common process ID.)  Linux‐
          Threads threads (including the manager thread) are visible as separate processes using ps(1).*

Comment: @cdarke Even then threads are managed by the kernel and execute in parallel. What the lecturer possibly meant was that POSIX does not prescribe this implementation of threads. In theory a POSIX-compliant implementation could create user threads that execute concurrently but not in parallel.

Comment: @cdarke: LinuxThreads were substituted by NPTL long ago.

Comment: @Obake: Maybe your lecturer is confusing pthreads with GNU pth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posix threads are kernel threads with glibc/musl (+possibly other pthread implementations) on Linux.

Comment: It is called [Native POSIX Thread Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library): _The Native POSIX Thread Library (NPTL) **is an implementation of the POSIX Threads specification** for the Linux operating system._

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between specification and implementation.

POSIX is a *specification* and (I think) your lecturer is correct that POSIX does not dictate that threads need to be managed by the kernel, and executed in parallel (at least I can’t find any related wording [in the official specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pthread.h.html)).

In practice, most major implementations — including (as mentioned in the other answer) on Linux via glibc, and on Windows via MinGW — implement pthreads via kernel system calls and execute them in parallel. So if your lecturer actually stated that pthreads are not kernel threads in concrete use then this is at least misleading, and arguably wrong.